# Update a column on a table from a table on another schema MySql

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I accidentally updated far more records than I should have with the wrong information. I have the correct information in another schema but I cannot figure out how to update the incorrect one.

I've tried something like -

```
Insert into schema1.table1 set columnName = (Select statement????) Where ?????
```

And then I get lost.
I've read around and tried a few answers out and I keep either getting a syntax error, or nothing happens.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
update schema1.table1
inner join schema2.table2
on schema1.table1.IDColumn = schema2.table2.IDColumn
set schema1.table1.column1 = schema2.table2.column2
```

This Worked for me