# Update table in one schema based on another schema table column in same database

Tags: mysql, database, sql-update, schema

I have two schemas in the same database. I want to update a table in one schema based on the table in another schema where the column value matches.
The structure of my database is as follows.

[structure of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nf7H.png)

As an example, this is my table named "p" in 1st schema that is "public" and have column "id" and "name"

```
id  name
3   Loral
1   Kim
2   Shawn
```

and this is the second table named "t" in the second schema that is "t_sc" and have column "id" and "name" but the names are different than table "p"

```
id  name
1   kylie
3   deny
2   tom
```

Now I want to update table "p" names according to table "t" names where the id matches.

I have tried the following query

**`update p set p.Name = t_sc.t.Name WHERE p.ID = t_sc.t.ID`**

but got the following error

**ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "t"**

I have tried multiple other ways too but I am not able to get the desired result. I am using Navicat for query and the database is Postgresql.

Comment: 'two schemas in the same database.' - in mysql schema is synonym for database so I'm not clear if the tables you refer to are in the same db or not. Also review multi table update in manual and fully qualify table names if required, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Comment: Oops didn't register the last sentence - If your db is postgresql you should amend the tags accordingly..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The schema are in the same database on the same server. I am new to database so I am not sure about how to explain certain thing. Sorry for confusion

Answer (score 0):

If this is really MySQL, you need to call your schema(s) specifically.

You can thank this user for the example below:

[Update a column on a table from a table on another schema MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27281970/update-a-column-on-a-table-from-a-table-on-another-schema-mysql)

```
update schema1.table1
inner join schema2.table2
on schema1.table1.IDColumn = schema2.table2.IDColumn
set schema1.table1.column1 = schema2.table2.column2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer myself. So I thought maybe I should post it for future visitors.

The query will be

```
UPDATE public.p a
SET name=b.name
FROM t_sc.t b
WHERE a.id=b.id
```

I was using the alias with column name `p.Name`  of the Table which I want to update. Also I was using the schema name at the wrong time `t_sc.t.Name` It was causing the error.